# How to convert a date format in semnatic-UI-Calendar?

Tags: javascript, calendar, semantic-ui

I am developing a web application where I am using this module as a datepicker calendar:

https://github.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI-Calendar

By default settings, when I select a date, it is input in the following format : 'October 12, 2016'

I want the selected date to be input in the following format '2016-10-12'

With reference to its API, I am using the following javascript code:

```
    <script>
             $(document)
    .ready(function() {
    $('.date_selecter').calendar({
  type: 'date'
});

                     })
  ;
    </script>
```

Does anyone know how to get the date in the format of 'yyyy-mm-dd'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the onChange event for the calendar instead of reading the value from the text field - this will give you a JavaScript Date object which you can then format yourself.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.date_selecter').calendar({
        type: 'date',
        onChange: function(date) {
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = date.getDate();
            if (month < 10) {
                month = '0' + month;
            }
            if (day < 10) {
                day = '0' + day;
            }

            // everything combined
            console.log(year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
        }
    });
});
```